# In UML, does composition imply an association class?

Tags: uml, normalization, composition

In a UML diagram where one class is comprised by another class, is there an implicit association table, or does it need to be shown?

For example, if I have Chapters that are composition of Paragraphs, is this alone enough:

[image: uml without explicit association class]

Or does the association class to be explicitly shown like so:

[image: uml with explicit association class]

I've never seen it done like that latter example, so I'm assuming it's implied. Or maybe I haven't normalized the data properly (considering chapter both appears in the Chapter class and the Paragraph class).

Comment: As a side note: you can not create a draft chapter with no contents with this model.

Comment: You don’t need a third table because the paragraph can have one FK to its chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, there is no implication. If you need an association class, you need to define it. However, UML is not about diagraming, it's about modeling. You can omit your association class in a diagram if you want to. The association class will still exist in your model, though.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not implied.

The reason why you haven't seen this is that in most cases it simply doesn't make sense. In the association class the class part additionally describes the properties of the association. In your example you create an artificial object that actually brings little or nothing. This kind of approach can be useful for many-to-many relationships which are impossible for composition (each part can have at most one whole). Even if you wanted to show Foreign Key it would simply be on one of the classes. But that's implied by the association itself. According to UML specification an inline attribute is equivalent to an association.

Moreover on UML you can depict many to many relationship simply but applying appropriate multiplicities on association ends. You may want to show the class depicting that only when modelling on the code level.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not implied.

UML is not about tables, but about classes. The author of the class diagram should tell the audience how a class should be interpreted. Some UML diagrams model the real world, others model a piece of application functionality and yet others depict a physical implementation.

Apparently, reading your question, you are modeling a relational database, where a class is a physical table. In that case, I would expect that every table is explicitly modeled as a UML class.

The UML standard does not demand this.

By the way, the notation (PK) and (FK) is not in accordance with the UML standard.